# With Visual studio 2015 send email with picture resized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project for work: I get emails from phones and the files are too big.  I would love to resize those huge files down a bit.   I am hoping someone can help me here thanks.  Here is the code it does not work.  The email part that follows works fine, so I did not include it.

```
    var  bmp = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
         var newImage = new Bitmap(200,200);
         var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
         g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 200, 200);

       string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                Attachment myAttachment = new 
       Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything with newImage after you draw it (ie save to file or write to stream). It's that you want to attach

Comment: I am still quite a newb, I am not sure what I would need to do to.  I would really like a way to attach the smaller file into myAttachment.  If this is not possible without saving first can someone let me know?